# Find CSS Path from JSoup Element

Tags: css, path, html-parsing, jsoup

Let's say I have [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) webpage and I'm considering the `td` element of the table containing the string `Doe`. Using Google Chrome I can get the *CSS Path* of that element:

```
#main > table:nth-child(6) > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(3)
```

Using that as Jsoup *CSS Query* returns the element I'm considering as you can see [here](http://try.jsoup.org/~RiApI7QEd-mR9YzCtJZHPcWzVKg).
 Is it possible with Jsoup to obtain the above *CSS Path* from an `Element` or I have to manually walk the tree to create it?

I know I could use the *CSS Query* `:containsOwn(text)` using the own text of the `Element`, but this could also select other elements, the path instead includes only classes, ids and `:nth-child(n)`.

This would be pretty useful to code a semantic parser in *JSoup* that will be able to extract similar elements.

Comment: What you are asking is not supported. It would be a nice feature though.

Comment: @alkis now jsoup supports it ;)

Comment: +1. Great job enrico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup doesn't seem to provide such a feature out-of-the-box. So I coded it:

```
public static String getCssPath(Element el) {
    if (el == null)
        return "";

    if (!el.id().isEmpty())
        return "#" + el.id();

    StringBuilder selector = new StringBuilder(el.tagName());
    String classes = StringUtil.join(el.classNames(), ".");
    if (!classes.isEmpty())
        selector.append('.').append(classes);

    if (el.parent() == null)
        return selector.toString();

    selector.insert(0, " > ");
    if (el.parent().select(selector.toString()).size() > 1)
        selector.append(String.format(
                ":nth-child(%d)", el.elementSiblingIndex() + 1));

    return getCssPath(el.parent()) + selector.toString();
}
```

I also created an [issue](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/462) and a [pull request](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/pull/459) on the Jsoup repository to extend the `Element` class with that method. Comment them or subscribe if you want it in Jsoup.

### UPDATE

My pull request was merged into jsoup version [1.8.1](http://jsoup.org/news/release-1.8.1), now the `Element` class has the method [`cssSelector`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#cssSelector()) which returns the CSS Path that can be used to retrieve the element in a selector:

> Get a CSS selector that will uniquely select this element.
> If the element has an ID, returns #id; otherwise returns the parent (if any)
> CSS selector, followed by '>', followed by a unique selector for the
> element (tag.class.class:nth-child(n)).